# WebService Error In CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I created a wsdl in eclipse and I generated classes using Apache CXF. And after that I integrated that service in Jetty Server. I implement server side code. I use SOAP UI tool to test the implementation of server. While I am executing the code i am getting the error like
**ERROR:**

```
WARN  23:47:30,240 | org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.TypeUtil | xsi:type absent, and no type available for sessionId
WARN  23:47:30,240 | org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.TypeUtil | xsi:type absent, and no type available for serverUrlenter code here
WARN  23:47:30,240 | org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.TypeUtil | xsi:type absent, and no type available for cipherTextValue
INFO  23:47:44,188 | org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor | Outbound Message
```

Here sessionId, serverUrl and cipherTextValue are the inputs. I don't know how to resolve this error. Can anybody tell me the answer. I blocked here.

**Sample XML Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dpa="http://ws.ciphercloud.com/dpaas/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dpa:detokenizeRequest>
         <sessionId>?</sessionId>
         <serverUrl>?</serverUrl>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <cipherTextValue>**ajgkjfagla009!</cipherTextValue>
      </dpa:detokenizeRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And one more thing is there any tutorials how to configure the webservices using Jetty.

Please reply to me. This is the blocker for me...

Thanx in advance.

---

Thanx for your reply bmargulies.

I use Aegis it works fine when i generate the wsdl from java code at that time my webservices are working fine. But i generated java code from the wsdl at that time i am getting this type of error. I am sending my appcontext.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- Load CXF modules from cxf.jar -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <!-- Enable message logging using the CXF logging feature -->
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <!-- The service bean -->
    <bean id="dataProtectionWebServiceImpl" class="com.ciphercloud.ws.dpaas.DataProtectionWebServiceImpl" />

    <!-- Aegis data binding -->
    <bean id="aegisBean" class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding"
        scope="prototype" />
    <bean id="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="dataBinding" ref="aegisBean" />
        <property name="serviceConfigurations">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceConfiguration" />
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisServiceConfiguration" />
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Service endpoint -->
    <!--
        See http://incubator.apache.org/cxf/faq.html regarding CXF + Spring
        AOP
    -->
    <jaxws:endpoint id="DataProtectionWebService"
        implementorClass="com.ciphercloud.ws.dpaas.DataProtectionWebServiceImpl"
        implementor="#dataProtectionWebServiceImpl" address="/ws">
        <jaxws:serviceFactory>
            <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory" />
        </jaxws:serviceFactory>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

This is my appcontext.xml. This is fine when java code to wsdl. But know the problem with Aegis when i generated code from wsdl to java.

As you said i will use jaxb instead of Aegis. Meanwhile is there any tutorial related to your concern please send me the links. Meanwhile i will also see this jaxb.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Aegis in a WSDL-first service. You have to use JAX-B.